# Scraping data from an HTML table with multiple pages

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, google-sheets, html-table

I have a website with a jsp page which returns data in the form of a table, and it consists of 81 pages. How can I scrape all this data into an Excel file, using Python?

I tried using innerHTML on Google sheets, which would have been perfect, except it only returns the values from the first page of the table.

Comment: Take a look at the urls for the first couple of pages; with any luck you will see a parameter like `?p=2`, `?p=3`, etc. Make a request for each of the required pages, extract the data, and concatenate.

Comment: Right, the URLs are in the form page=1,2, etc. Is there any way I can loop these requests in Google sheets? Python web scraping is a pain, especially when I have to write to an Excel, but if that's the only way, then I will do it.

Comment: If you have Pandas, it's very easy: `pandas.read_html()` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()` should make this about a four-line program.

Comment: Great thanks, pandas worked perfectly! If you list that as an answer I would gladly accept it.